# Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, nib

I don't know why I'm getting this error:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle < /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/D49DC6F2-7AE0-4BBD-97FB-AB9D869C48FE/Fish Quiz.app> (loaded)' with name 'Taxo2ViewController'' *

I checked all of the similar posts regarding this error but still my app generate this error. I checked all of my nib files, checked their types and they are all similar.

My app is a quiz; I have 5 questions each round. This error occurs after answering 45+ rounds of questions. I wonder why this is happen even though my app works at first. Please help me with this.

Thanks Everyone! Cheers!
Kim

Comment: Do you have Taxo2ViewController.xib file? It it marked to copy in `Copy Bundle Resourses`?

Comment: Can you give the code snippet in which you are loading your nib file and snapshots of your nib file?

Comment: @Nekto - Yes I have the Taxo2ViewController.xib in my project. Sometimes the error reported my other controller, sometimes it is Taxo3ViewController or Taxo4 or 5.

Comment: @Darshan These are the links for my code and screenshots
http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/9563/ss1wo.png
http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/8292/ss2el.png
http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/4135/ss3q.png
http://img847.imageshack.us/img847/5151/taxo1.png
http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/1903/taxo2.png

* ss1wo is my function to proceed to the next controller
* ss2el is my function that calls ss1wo, I included sound there if the user gets the correct answer. also a delay.
* ss3q is my event for buttons to get the user's answer.
* img847 and img5 is my taxo1 and 2 ViewController.xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to write your code correctly. Take a look at it again and see if there are mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I seen your code you provided in the links above. I found problem in your goToNext function given in first link above. What you have done is, you are having one view controller having two xib files, that is your TaxO2ViewController has two xib files. So in each of these two xib files the owner should be your TaxO2ViewController and the view property of TaxO2ViewController  should be bound to both of this xib files. Probably you do not have done that.

Comment: I have an existing code for this, its actually the same, its working and not generating any error like this. The error occurs after playing the game 45+ times. If its really a problem the app should not work during the first run.